# Type arguments supplied to .NET generic constructor, yet still causing an error as if not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this snippet of seemingly un-problematic code in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor application:

```
@{
    IDictionary htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

This is generating the error,

> *"Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary' requires 2 type arguments".*

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to give it on the left hand side also:

```
IDictionary<string, string> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Note that the error message is talking about `IDictionary`, not `Dictionary`.

Or, if you *do* want the non-generic [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) interface, make sure that its namespace (`System.Collections`) is in scope.

Comment: Doh! Thank you very much. This is something I needed quickly for a job I hope to get, so your quick response is much appreciated.